# Android- Json to arraylist , org.json.JSONException org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

Tags: php, android, json

**Error:**

> org.json.JSONException: Value [{"username":"ghs"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

**Code at android end:**

```
public void listdrawer(){
            onlineList_uname = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("username");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("username");
                onlineList_uname.add(i,name);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**php end:**

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$sql = "select b.username from l_s a,user_table b where a.user_id=b.user_id    and status = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
// output data of each row
while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$tem = $row;
$json = json_encode($tem);
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($json);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: please print your json in php code.and show to us!

Comment: can you add your whole json? Im just wondering that `jsonResponse.getJSONArray("username");`  username seems wrong.. should be an array attribute something like "value"??, username is an object property isnt it?

Comment: Ohh can you please explain new to Json....

Answer (score 1):

if your jsonResult = `[{"username":"g4"},{"username":"ghs"},{"username":"g"},{"username":"e"},{"username":"a"}]`

**Code:**

```
ArrayList<String> onlineList_uname = new ArrayList<>();
String jsonResult = "[{\"username\":\"g4\"},{\"username\":\"ghs\"},{\"username\":\"g\"},{\"username\":\"e\"},{\"username\":\"a\"}]"; // = [{"username":"g4"},{"username":"ghs"},{"username":"g"},{"username":"e"},{"username":"a"}]

try {
  JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(jsonResult);

  for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jObj.getString("username");
    onlineList_uname.add(i, name);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < onlineList_uname.size(); j++) {
    Log.i("LOG", "username#" + j + " " + onlineList_uname.get(j));
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**result :**

username#0 g4

username#1 ghs

username#2 g

username#3 e

username#4 a

Comment: Okay will try it today

Comment: Still getting same error at line JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(jsonResult);

Comment: what is your jsonResult ?! give it to us.

Comment: [{"username":"g4"},{"username":"ghs"},{"username":"g"},{"use‌​rname":"e"},{"userna‌​me":"a"}]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jsonChildNode.optString("username").toString();
```

I think I had the same issue before and toString method solved it.

Comment: Okay will try it today

Comment: Still same error ... rg.json.JSONException: Value [{"username":"g4"},{"username":"ghs"},{"username":"g"},{"username":"e"},{"username":"a"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-03 09:50:56.018 20463-20463/in.chaosgamerz.gameheadshot W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

Comment: Sure.. This is the JSON   [{"username":"g4"},{"username":"ghs"},{"username":"g"},{"use‌​rname":"e"},{"userna‌​me":"a"}]

Comment: @HemantVyas above Erfan's code works fine...copy his code it works fine

Comment: your jsonResult is wrong than if it doesnt work. Try putting Log to see what is actually giving you